# Laravel Valet failed to open stream error

Tags: php, laravel, server, laravel-valet

I have viewed and tried the below article suggestion:

[Laravel & Valet: Failed to open stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478933/laravel-valet-failed-to-open-stream)

none of this worked for me.

the only way to solve this is from me to rename the project folder.

if I do that, it works. the question is, why all of the sudden am I facing this issue. tried updating, installing clearing cache and all with composer and npm.

Does anyone know the exact reason for this issue?

error as below

```php
Warning: require(/Users/exp/Dev/urs/x/vendor/composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/exp/Dev/urs/x/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/exp/Dev/urs/x/vendor/composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.7/share/php/pear') in /Users/exp/Dev/urs/x/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

Comment: What's your project folder name exactly?

Comment: It's x, i.e project folder name.

Comment: Ok, I just want to confirm is the project folder contains space or not..

Comment: No noting. The name itself is x.